# GNU Autotools with TCC

Tags: c, autotools, tcc

I recently discovered the Tiny C Compiler. For the project that I'm currently working on, performance is not a real issue, but file size is, making TCC ideal. I'm using Autotools as a build manager, and I figured that using TCC would be as simple as `./configure CC=tcc`.

However, this returns `checking whether the C compiler works... no`. In config.log, it says `configure: exit 77`.

Despite all of this, setting `CC=clang` works fine. Is there any way to get Autotools to use TCC?

Comment: automake has only recently been addding support (partial) for tcc. Check if you have tools that have this support. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autotools-announce/2012-12/msg00001.html

Comment: My version of Autotools seems to support it. However, the issue appears to have been with my CFLAGS.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to have been the fault of my CFLAGS. While TCC was normally able to compile programs with them, Autotools seems to have thought otherwise. Setting CFLAGS="" resolved the issue.

For future reference, my CFLAGS are `-march=native -mtune=native -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4`.

Answer (score 0):

iirc tcc does not produce tiny executables - it is tcc itself that is tiny. Perhaps you're looking for `gcc -Os`?

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: Nope. TCC produces small executables, partially because of its simplicity and lack of optimization. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler